# Why react add css inline in develop and in production don't add

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I'm in development I get several style tags, but when I'm in production they do not appear

[image]

how to make them appear in production?

Comment: Are you using any other libraries besides React? Or are you maybe using a module bundler like webpack or rollup? React alone shouldn't cause any CSS to be added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a bundler in use which creates a single large CSS file with all the styles in it. Check the files in your build folder to confirm.